# Elasticsearch cumulative sum aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Hi i am new to elasticsearch and trying to construct a query which aggregates the no of projetcs created over time. i have created a script but it only return 10 values initially. When i do min_doc_count = 1 in date_histogram it gives an exception :

> Validation failed : parent histogram of cumulative sum
> aggregation([cumulative_count] must have min_doc_count of 0;

Is there any other way i can do this ?

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "monthly_buckets": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "project_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "projectname"
          }
        },
        "cumulative_count": {
          "cumulative_sum": {
            "buckets_path": "project_count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than 10 months of data?

Comment: Yes it has aroud 2 years of data. But it only returns 10.

Comment: That means you the oldest data was 2 years ago, the most recent one is from this month but you have months inbetween that might have no data, is that possible? i.e. only 10 months out of the 24 last months actually contain data. If this is the case, then what you're seeing works as designed (since `min_doc_count` must be 1).